# PostgreSQL 15.3 installation problems on pgAdmin(The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

### pgAdmin Runtime Environment

Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\TOSH\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment:

- ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
- APPDATA: C:\Users\TOSH\AppData\Roaming
- CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \.\pipe\crashpad_244_ITLJXRKGXHYRHCMN
- CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
- CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
- CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
- CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
- COMPUTERNAME: TOSHIBA
- ComSpec: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
- DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
- easyplussdk: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin"
- FP_NO_HOST_CHECK: NO
- HOMEDRIVE: C:
- HOMEPATH: \Users\TOSH
- LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\TOSH\AppData\Local
- LOGONSERVER: \TOSHIBA
- NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 4
- OneDrive: C:\Users\TOSH\OneDrive
- OneDriveConsumer: C:\Users\TOSH\OneDrive
- OPENSSL_CONF: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf
- OS: Windows_NT
- 

---

Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.239 Sec

i just try to fix a lot of time however yet now not working`